# ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server

Tags: mariadb

So I keep having this error on my sql

> ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '   CONSTRAINT `fk_examinee_user1`
>       FOREIGN KEY (`userName`)
>       REFERENCES `q' at line 12

SQL Code:

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `questionnaire`.`examinee`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questionnaire`.`examinee` (
      `examineeNumber` INT NOT NULL,
      `userName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `examineeID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `startDate` INT NOT NULL,
      `endDate` INT NOT NULL,
      `Active` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`examineeID`),
      INDEX `fk_examinee_user1_idx` (`userName` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_examinee_user1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`userName`)
        REFERENCES `questionnaire`.`user` (`userName`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Tried everything but code seems right to me. please help

Comment: Most likely your MariaDB version is not allowing `VISIBLE` clause in `INDEX fk_examinee_user1_idx (userName ASC) VISIBLE,`

Comment: What is `VISIBLE`?

Comment: @Marvin The opposite of invisible?

Comment: Can you publish table user please.

Comment: Yes, please add the definition of the table **user**. The problem may be there.

Comment: Which version of MariaDB?

Comment: Hello.. here is my table for user

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questionnaire`.`user` (
  `userID` INT NOT NULL,
  `userName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` TEXT(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `role` TEXT(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userName`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

Comment: so i tried removing VISIBLE, and it was successful. Any idea why it behaves like that so I can better understand?